# Regular expression matching either an empty string or a string in a given set

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match either "direction" (`">"` or `"<"`) from a string like `"->"`, `"<=="`, `"..."`. When the string contains no direction, I want to match `""`. More precisely, the equivalent Python expression would be:

```py
">" if ">" in s else ("<" if "<" in s else "")
```

I first came up with this simple regular expression:

```py
re.search(r"[<>]|", s)[0]
```

... but it evaluates to `""` as soon as the direction is not in the first position. How would you do that?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for requiring a single regex?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. I suspect I am not able to see some obvious solution.

Comment: I suspect that any such RE would actually be slower than the Python expression.

Comment: If you use [such as `[><]|$` on input like `->`](https://regex101.com/r/z47DaG/1) this will always give you at least two matches, because every string has an end. An alternative to only match an empty string if there is no `<` or `>` contained in the whole string can be to use an alternation with a *lookahead* at start: [`[><]|^(?=[^><]*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/yaTAIw/1) Just to mention, though it does not mattcher much... when using `[0]` (first match), there will be one anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler version of [Andrej Kesely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985)'s solution:

```py
re.search('<|>|$', s)[0]
```

Comment: I think this cannot be made more compact. Cheers!

Comment: And your solution generalizes to: matching one among several given substrings s1, s2, ..., or "" if none is present: `s1|s2|...|$`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want pure `re` solution ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TBimCf/2)):

```py
import re

test_cases = [
    "->", "<==", "..."
]

for t in test_cases:
    print(re.search('(?=[<>]).|$', t)[0])
```

Prints:

```
>
<
```

---

This will match first `<` or `>` string or end of string `$` (then it returns empty string `''`)

---

EDIT: Simplified the regex, thanks @InSync

Comment: Why is the first `|$` necessary?

Comment: Very interesting! I was trying to use one lookbehind anchor, but this one works perfectly. I will wait before accepting your solution, in case someone else (or you) can provide a more elementary solution.

Comment: @InSync Yeah, it's not necessary. I think Unmitigated solution is the simplest one.

Comment: `(?=.)[<>]|$` seems to work too, or am I missing something? Edit: yes, it's nothing new.

Comment: @Aristide Then the first `(?=.)` is not necessary, just `[<>]|$`

Comment: Yes, I just found that, too! So, my initial take was just missing a closing `$`. Very funny!

Answer (score 2):

The reason this regex `[<>]|` returns "" if the first character is not `<` or `>` is because the alternation in this case always matches the position, returning a zero length match for [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)

Instead of writing if/else statements or a regex, you could also use [next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) which can return a default value and list the strings that you want to match in an array:

```
test_str = "this is a test string with > and <"
items = ["<", ">"]
item = next((i for i in items if i in test_str), "")
print(item)
```